# HttpWebRequest/Response not recovering after "ipconfig /release" and "ipconfig /renew"

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I've written a small Windows Service to check the availability of a website.I noticed it failing due to the NIC going to sleep but the Request isn't able to recover even after the NIC woke up.

I'm able to reproduce the problem by  simply using a "ipconfig /release" and "ipconfig /renew" on a WinForm that check the site.

Here is the code:

```
private void checkSite()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebSite);
        HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        try
        {                
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                UpdateResult(response.StatusCode + " --> " + response.StatusDescription);
            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            UpdateResult(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            request = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Launching `checkSite()` works until I try to disconnect the NIC (ipconfig /release), after that it obviously fails with `The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.it'`. **After reconnecting the NIC** (ipconfig /renew) the **method continuously fails** with `Unable to connect to the remote server`.
The only way to have it working again is to close the program and start it again.

What am I missing?

ps: I forced a `GC.Collect()` because the used memory of the process grows after every `checkSite()` (somehow it doesn't get collected even when checking every 2 minutes).

---

Edit: I found out that the request ServicePoint is storing the DefaultProxy as I asked in the app.config:

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
 </system.net>
```

after "ipconfig /release" the ServicePoint lose everything about the Proxy and "ipconfig /renew" doesn't change anything in the ServicePoint, it is not using the Proxy.

---

Edit2: the request is losing the default Proxy in the process:

- first request goes through the default Proxy as specified in the
  app.config;
- `ipconfig /release`;
- a second request is sent, doesn't use the proxy;
- `ipconfig /renew`;
- a third request is sent, still doesn't use the proxy.

Is it possible to force back the Default Proxy?
I tried this but to no avail:

```
IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
request.Proxy = webProxy;
```

Comment: Is `ServicePointManager` caching the can't resolve state?

Comment: Thanks @Richard, how can I check for this? I looked around but I'm not able to find nothing useful in that class to verify its cache.

Comment: Other than setting a connection group name so it can be cleared, the whole `ServicePoint` and `ServicePointManager` API is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by **resetting the DefaultWebProxy** in the `catch` body:

```
 WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
 WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Thanks to Richard for pointing me in the right direction.